# How to debug error in dynamic PIVOT code?

Tags: sql-server

I have this:

```
DECLARE 
@columns NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',
@sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT @columns += QUOTENAME(CAST(ondate as date)) + ','
FROM AuditLogUnique
WHERE CAST(ondate as date) >= '06/22/2020'
ORDER BY CAST(ondate as date)
SET @columns = LEFT(@columns, LEN(@columns) - 1);

SET @sql = '
SELECT * FROM   
(
SELECT systemuserid, COUNT(systemuserid) FROM [AuditLogUnique]
WHERE CAST(ondate as date) >= ''06/22/2020''
GROUP BY systemuserid
) t

PIVOT(
COUNT(systemuserid) 
FOR CAST(ondate as date) IN ('+ @columns +')
) AS pivot_table;';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;
```

It fails with Incorrect syntax near '('.

It's my first attempt using PIVOT and not sure how to debug it.

Thanks.

Comment: You must SEE it in order to debug it. Rather than executing the statement you build dynamically, you should select it. In SSMS you might need to adjust query output options to see the entire string.

Comment: Get a statement working *without* dynamic SQL first. I think you need to _not_ `CAST(ondate as date)` inside the pivot, just use `FOR ondate IN (` but you should be using standard date formats, not this ambiguous regional format.

Answer (score 0):

Just add print prior to execute the dynamic SQL and you can figure out the errors by running the code separately.

Following points might help:

You should use `distinct` while preparing the `@columns` otherwise it could fail in the later part.

Use `ondate` in the select as well prior to pivoting it.

Do not use `cast` inside `pivot`, rather make `@columns` similar to the raw `ondate` column.